# SQLite Foreign Key Constraint Failed (code 787) - Android Room

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I am having problem with Foreign key in Android Room.

I wrote two entities and dao. Customer entity has addressesId param, which is a reference to a foreign key.

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "customers", foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = AddressDbModel::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["address_id"]
        )
    ],
    indices = [
        Index(value = ["address_id"])
    ]
)
data class CustomerDbModel(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val customerId: Long? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "address_id")
    val addressId: Long? = null
)
```

```
@Entity(tableName = "addresses")
data class AddressDbModel(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Long? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "street_address")
    val street: String? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "city")
    val city: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "building_number")
    val buildingNumber: String? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "flat_number")
    val flatNumber: String? = null
)
```

```
@Dao
interface AddressDao : BaseDao<AddressDbModel> {

    @Query("DELETE FROM addresses WHERE id=:address")
    fun deleteById(address: Long)
}
```

when I execute the "deleteById" method, then app throw exception,

```
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY[787])
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use :-

```
ForeignKey(
        entity = AddressDbModel::class,
        parentColumns = ["id"],
        childColumns = ["address_id"],
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
)
```

Thus if an address is deleted the child/children, if any, will be deleted. You may want to consider `onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE` (although this is less likely to be needed).

You may wish look at [SQLite Foreign Key Support](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)